# Angular 2: How to test that an NgBootstrap component (and contents) are on the page?

Tags: angular, jasmine, integration-testing, ng-bootstrap

This problem keeps coming up in my tests, where I'm trying to test the contents of an element inside an NgBootstrap component (like a modal). It seems like the test can't even tell that the component exists, even though the Karma browser page displays the component just fine.

For example, I'm using an NgbModal; it's wrapped in `<ng-template>` and renders by calling the NgModal's `open` method, which is passed the modal's content via a template reference variable, as per the [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) , and when it renders onscreen, the markup is like:

```
<ngb-modal-window role="dialog" style="display: block;" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade show">
    <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
  <div _ngcontent-c0="" id="save-modal">
    <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="modal-header">
      <h4 _ngcontent-c0="" class="modal-title">Confirm changes</h4>
      <button _ngcontent-c0="" class="close" aria-label="Close" type="button">
        <span _ngcontent-c0="" class="ng-tns-c0-0" aria-hidden="true" title="Close">×</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="modal-body">
      <p>Save changes?</p>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="modal-footer">
      <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="flex">
        <button _ngcontent-c0="" class="btn btn-link mr3" aria-label="Close" type="button">
            <span _ngcontent-c0="" class="ng-tns-c0-0" aria-hidden="true" title="Cancel">Cancel</span>
          </button>
        <button _ngcontent-c0="" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" title="Save the update">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
    </ngb-modal-window>
```

Yet, if in the test I try `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ngb-modal-window'))`
or `By.css('#save-modal')` (a DIV within the modal) neither return the HTML element. Yes, I'm using `fixture.detectChanges()`. I just don't know if the test still isn't "seeing" the component (and what to do about that) or if `By.css` can't search for non-standard HTML elements, or what.

**New info**: As I'm using VS Code, I can debug the test and have a breakpoint on my assertion:

```
tick(); //desperately trying anything, even though nothing async is going on
fixture.detectChanges();
let modalEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ngb-modal-window'));
expect(modalEl).toBeDefined('defined'); //<===breakpoint here
```

when looking at the karma browser page, the modal is *not* opened yet; only when I continue the code does the modal pop up. **So what else do I need to do to get the view to update when I've already called detectChanges()**?

Answer (score 2):

The modal is not a child of your component. It's included in the body of the document. So you can just use the document to find your modal:

```
document.querySelector('ngb-modal-window');
```

or

```
document.querySelector('.modal-content');
```

You can use the [ng-bootstrap tests](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.spec.ts) as an inspiration:

Comment: I didn't think `By.css()` searched for children anyway, isn't it just looking at for the predicate in whatever `debugElement` it's called on?

Comment: In any case, at that breakpoint, whether using `document.querySelector` or `By.css`, `modalEl` is set to the HTML element; it's not null or undefined, but just empty.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work either. document.querySelectAll('div') does not find any divs beyond the div associated with ngb-panel.